# How to display 1.0% as 1% in SSRS expression

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2017

I am calculating percentage and formatting the value as "0.0". That give me values like 3.7%, 4.1% etc. But when it's 1.0% I want to show as 1% only, how to remove decimal when the there is a whole value? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming your database values are in decimal format so that 0.01 represents 1%.

If this is not the case, let me know and I will modify the answer.

I created some test data with

```
SELECT 0.09 as pc
UNION SELECT 0.091
UNION SELECT 0.099
UNION SELECT 0.01
UNION SELECT 0.011
UNION SELECT 0.012
UNION SELECT 0.019
UNION SELECT 0.020
UNION SELECT 0.021
```

I then added a table to show the raw value plus various other formats.

Finally I added a 4th column that formats the value based on if it is a 'whole percent' or not.

I set the `Format` property of the textbox to the following expression.

```
=IIF(
    Fields!pc.Value * 100 = CINT(Fields!pc.Value*100)
    , "p0"
    , "p1"
    )
```

This basically checks if the value when multiplied by 100 is an integer, if it is then we apply `p0` as the format code, if not we apply `p1` as the format code.

The end result is as follows.

[image]

**Note:** We have only changed the format property of the textbox, **not** the value expression.

As you can see in the design below, each column's value expression is identical ([pc]), it is only the format property of each textbox that is different. To show the properties panel click on the textbox and then hit F4 in Visual Studio. If you are using Report Builder then I'm not sure if F4 works, but there is a menu option to show the properties panel somewhere.

Finally, you will obviously need to replace the field `pc` from my example with the actual field name in your report.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. =IIF(
    Fields!pc.Value * 100 = CINT(Fields!pc.Value*100)
    , "p0"
    , "p1"
    )     gives me "p0". Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: You need to change the format property, not the value expression. So, change the textbox back to how is was, then with the textbox selected, look for the `Format` property in the properties panel (F4 if you cannot see this) and set the format expression to the expression I gave in my answer. Obviously `pc` needs to be replaced with the name of the field you want formatting. I'll add a screen shot later to make it clear

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It is working perfectly fine now.. I was changing the value expression instead of the format property.

Answer (score 0):

How about you wrap an iff statement around your formating?

Something along the lines of

```
=iif(round(Fields!num.Value) = Fields!num.Value,format(Fields!num.Value,"0%"),format(Fields!num.Value,"0.00%"))
```

This evaluates the output and if it is 1.0% then it makes it 1% else formats the rest of the value as required

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It worked but only for value 1.0. If runtime calculated answer is for example 5.0% then it still showing as 5.0%.

Comment: Thanks Harry. It is working now. I tried yours and Alan's answers and both are working. Thank you!